# Bootstrap classes not working - min-vh-100, shadow

Tags: bootstrap-4

This is a quick question since I'm just getting the hang of bootstrap. Most classes work without any problems. But some classes just don't seem to be applied. Two examples are: `min-vh-100` and `shadow`.

Did I forget to include a relevant CSS file?

[See Codepen](https://codepen.io/florianmartens/pen/NWGYPmp)

Comment: You didn't include Bootstrap CSS files in the Codepen example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `min-vh-100` and `shadow` class in Bootstrap version 4.0.0. Can you upgrade to version 4.4.1?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```